# Обращение к свойствам класса в коллекции c#

Tags: c#

Есть коллекция типа некого класса, которая заполнена объектами данного класса. Нужно обратиться к свойству этого класса и присвоить его какой-то переменной (например "qwer"). У каждых объектов разное свойство, так что нужно как-то указать индекс объекта, расположенного в коллекции, и вытащить из указанного объекта свойство.

```
public class Class
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
List<Class> list = new List<Class>();
string qwer;
```

Comment: ну так по индексу и укажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: я знаю только что можно найти определенный элемент что-то типа: `list.Find(x => x.Name == "dawdawd")`  но как вот найти элемент без сравнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если индекс известен, то:

```
public class Class
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
List<Class> list = new List<Class>();
list.Add(new Class { Name = "someName" });

int index = 0;
string qwer = list[index].Name
```

Answer (score 0):

доступ к полю класса, которым параметризирована колекция можна получить несколькими способами:

1) если мы знаем индекс элемента к нему можно обратится напрямую

```
//здесь переменной qwer мы присваиваем значение поля Name третьего элемента коллекции
qwer = list[2].Name;
```

2) если мы знаем одно из значений поля элемента и оно уникально (например это поле Id, случай не наш ибо у нас только одно поле но если бы поле Id и оно было бы уникальным то обратится к элементу коллекции его содержащему можно так)

```
//someValue - значение которое нам заведомо известно
var item = list.Find(x=>x.Id == someValue);
qwer = item.Name;
```

3) мы хотим обратится к полю Name всех элементов коллекции

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
     qwer = list[i].Name;       
}
```

или так

```
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    qwer = item.Name;
}
```

тут нужно понимать что мы постоянно присваиваем новое значение одной и той же переменной qwer, то есть перезаписываем ее, после завершения циклов переменная qwer будет содержать значение поля Name последнего єлемента коллекции.